# how do i change the woocommerce_sale_flash part on a multilanguage site?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building a multilingual site with WP using Woocommerce.

The client asked me to change the Sale Flash text, after some research i found this code

```
add_filter('woocommerce_sale_flash', 'avia_change_sale_content', 10, 3);
function avia_change_sale_content($content, $post, $product){
$content = '<span class="onsale">'.__( 'Sale custom text!', 'woocommerce' ).'</span>';
return $content;
}
```

It works just fine, but it also changes the german and spanish text - replacing it with the english one.

I checked at the WPML strings (hoping to translate it through that system), but couldn't find it there.

Does anyone know what filter i would have to set to create custom flash sale text in english, spanish and german

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the text correctly, however the issue is that the new string is not found in the language files provided by WooCommerce. The plugin will load a domain called `"woocommerce"` which is then used to locate strings and their translations if necessary. You are passing the text into `__()` ([more info on `__()', '_e()`, `_x()`, `_n()`](http://wpengineer.com/2237/whats-the-difference-between-__-_e-_x-and-_ex/)), but because your text is new, it isn't found in the dictionary provided by WooCommerce so it defaults to English.

```
// the __() function can't find 'Sale custom text' in the 'woocommerce' text domain, 
// so it does not translate. 
__( 'Sale custom text!', 'woocommerce' )
```

To have this text translate, you will need to load your own language files and text domain and pass the text through `__()` using your custom domain.

The short version of how to do this:

- Use a custom text domain

  ```
  // load text from 'my_text_domain'
  __( 'Sale custom text!', 'my_text_domain' )
  ```
- Download and install [PoEdit](http://poedit.net/) to create *.po language files. It has options to scan PHP files for translations entries and will add them to your dictionary. There are tutorials on this on the Internet.
- Create one translation file per language that you want to support
- Create a folder called `languages` under your theme directory (this should be a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) so that updates don't overwrite your work), or plugin directory if you are doing your customizations that way.
- Update your `functions.php` (or other plugin, etc) to load your custom text domain. Make sure to use the appropriate path, this assumes it's in the theme.

  ```
  function load_textdomain_my_text_domain() {
      $language_dir = get_template_directory() . '/languages/';
      load_plugin_textdomain( 'my_text_domain', false, $language_dir );
  }
  add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'load_textdomain_my_text_domain' );
  ```

An example of doing this in a plugin using one I wrote:

- Spanish language files create by PoEdit under the [`/languages` directory](https://github.com/doublesharp/validated-field-for-acf/tree/master/languages).
- Loading the language files under a [custom text domain](https://github.com/doublesharp/validated-field-for-acf/blob/master/validated_field.php#L27).
- Text being passed through [`__()` using the custom text domain](https://github.com/doublesharp/validated-field-for-acf/blob/master/validated_field_v4.php#L36).